# Что может настырно резать Iframe?

Tags: php

При публикации поста, обрезается тег iframe, публикуется пост через обычную textarea.

**Как можно избавиться от обрезки тега?**

в самой функции `add_feed` нашел такое:

```
$content = sanitizeText($content);
```

Сама функция sanitizetext:

```
if (!function_exists('sanitizeText')) {
function sanitizeText($string, $limit = false, $output = false) {
    if (!is_string($string)) return $string;
    $lawed_config = array(
        'safe' => 1,
        'deny_attribute' => 'id, style, class'
    );
    $string = lawedContent($string, $lawed_config);//great one
    $string = trim($string);
    //$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);

    $string = str_replace('&amp;#', '&#',$string);
    $string = str_replace('&amp;', '&',$string);
$string = preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $string, $match);

    if ($limit) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $limit);
    }
    return $string;
}

}
```

Еще такие подозрительные функции:

```
function format_output_text($content) {
$content = str_replace("\r\n", '<br />',$content);
$content = str_replace("\n", '<br />',$content);
$content = str_replace("\r", '<br />',$content);
$content = stripslashes($content);
$content = autoLinkUrls($content);
if ($content) $content = fire_hook('filter.content', $content);
$content = ($content);
$lawed_config = array(
    'safe' => 1,
    'deny_attribute' => 'id, style, class'
);
$content = lawedContent($content, $lawed_config);
//replace bad words
$badWords = config('ban_filters_words', '');
if ($badWords) {
    $badWords = explode(',', $badWords);
    foreach($badWords as $word) {
        $content = str_replace($word, '***', $content);
    }
}

return $content;
```

}

```
function output_text($content, $options = array('html' => true, 'length' => 500, 'more' => true)) {
/**
 * @var $html
 * @var $length
 * @var $more
 */
extract($options);
$content = format_output_text($content);
$tContent = $content;
$original = $content;

if (is_rtl($content)) {
    $content = "<span style='direction: rtl;text-align: right;display: block'>{$content}</span>";
}
//too much text solution
$id = md5($tContent.time());
$result = "<span id='{$id}' style='font-weight: normal !important'>";
if ($more === true) {
    if (strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($tContent, '<br>'))) > $length) {
        $result .= "<span class='text-full' style='display: none;font-weight: normal'>{$content}</span>";
        $tContent = format_output_text(str_limit($tContent, $length, array('ending' => '...', 'html' => $html)));
        if (is_rtl($tContent)) $tContent = "<span style='direction: rtl;text-align: right;display:block'>{$tContent}</span>";
        $result .= "<span style='font-weight: normal !important'>".$tContent."</span>";
        $result .= '<a href="" onclick=\'return read_more(this, "'.$id.'")\'>'.lang('read-more').'</a>';
    } else {
        $result .= $content;
    }
} elseif($more) {
    $result .= "<span class='text-full' style='display: none;font-weight: normal'>{$content}</span>";
    $tContent = format_output_text(str_limit($tContent, $length, array('ending' => '...', 'html' => $html)));
    if (is_rtl($tContent)) $tContent = "<span style='direction: rtl;text-align: right;display:block'>{$tContent}</span>";
    $result .= "<span style='font-weight: normal !important'>".$tContent."</span>";
    $result .= '<a href="'.$more.'" ajax="true">'.lang('read-more').'</a>';
} else {
    $result .= $content;
}

$result .= "</span>";
if (config('enable-text-translation', false) and !empty($original) and !isEnglish($original)) {
    $trans = lang('see-translation');
    $result .= "<div id='{$id}-translation' class='non-translated'><input name='text' type='hidden' value='{$original}'/><button data-id='{$id}' onclick='return translateText(this)'>{$trans}</button></div>";
}
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Что это за куски кода и как они связаны с вопросом? Пожалуйста, предоставьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы мы поняли связь всего этого и смогли повторить у себя вашу проблему

Comment: ищите конфиг этой приблуды, возможно там приведен список разрешенных (или запрещенных) тэгов.